# /tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - AWS Lambda playwright

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, chromium, playwright

When I try to run code in AWS Lambda I get below error

```
/tmp/chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The chromium browser initializes and code works first time but throws above error when I request again. Using
nodejs 16.x,
playwright 1.29+ ,
@sparticuz/chromium 119.x,
lambda runtime nodejs16.x

Using @sparticuz/chromium for chromium browser. Earlier used playwright-aws-lambda but didn't face above issue with this package.

```
const chromium = require('@sparticuz/chromium')
const {chromium: p} = require("playwright-core")
await p.launch({
    executablePath: chromium.executablePath(),
    defaultViewport: chromium.deafultViewport,
    headless: true 
    args: [...chromium.args, '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--no-sandbox']
})
```

Comment: Adding the package as lambda layer helped.